# Read xml from an external jar not included in classpath

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jar, javafx

I created a javafx project using Netbeans, the project itself works just fine.

I'm now trying to implement a custom light-weight plugin system, the plugins are external JARs located inside the `plugins/` directory of the main project. I'm using `javax.security` package to sandbox the plugins.

Here's the main project's structure:

```
MainProject
  |
  |---plugins/
  |   |---MyPlugin.jar
  |
  |---src/
  |   |---main.app.plugin
  |       |---Plugin.java
  |       |---PluginSecurityPolicy.java
  |       |---PluginClassLoader.java
  |       |---PluginContainer.java
  ....
```

And the plugin's one:

```
Plugin
  |
  |---src/
  |   |---my.plugin
  |   |   |---MyPlugin.java
  |   |--settings.xml
  |
  |---dist/
      |---MyPlugin.jar
          |---META-INF/
          |   |---MANIFEST.MF
          |---my.plugin
          |   |---MyPlugin.class
          |---settings.xml
```

To load the plugins into the program i've made a `PluginContainer` class that gets all the jar files from the plugins directory, lists all file inside the jar and lookup for the plugin file and the settings file.

I can load and make an instance of the plugin class, but when it comes to the XML there's no way i can even list it among the jar contents.

Here's the code, maybe someone can see where i did it wrong.

PluginSecurityPolicy.java

```
import java.security.AllPermission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class PluginSecurityPolicy extends Policy {

    @Override
    public PermissionCollection getPermissions(ProtectionDomain domain) {
        if (isPlugin(domain)) {
            return pluginPermissions();
        } else {
            return applicationPermissions();
        }        
    }

    private boolean isPlugin(ProtectionDomain domain) {
        return domain.getClassLoader() instanceof PluginClassLoader;
    }

    private PermissionCollection pluginPermissions() {
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
        //
        return permissions;
    }

    private PermissionCollection applicationPermissions() {
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
        permissions.add(new AllPermission());
        return permissions;
    }
}
```

PluginClassLoader.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class PluginClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public PluginClassLoader(URL jarFileUrl) {
        super(new URL[] {jarFileUrl});
    }
}
```

PluginContainer.java, the `#load` method is the one

```
import main.app.plugin.PluginClassLoader;
import main.app.plugin.PluginSecurityPolicy;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class PluginContainer {
    private ArrayList<Plugin> plugins;
    private ManifestParser parser;

    public PluginContainer() {
        Policy.setPolicy(new PluginSecurityPolicy());
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        parser = new ManifestParser();
    }

    public void init() {
        File[] dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/plugins").listFiles();
        for (File pluginJarFile : dir) {
            try {
                Plugin plugin = load(pluginJarFile.getCanonicalPath());
                plugins.add(plugin);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public <T extends Plugin> T getPlugin(Class<T> plugin) {
        for (Plugin p : plugins) {
            if (p.getClass().equals(plugin)) {
                return (T)p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Plugin load(String pluginJarFile) throws Exception { 
        PluginManifest manifest = null;
        Plugin plugin = null;

        // Load the jar file
        ZipFile jarFile = new ZipFile(pluginJarFile);            

        // Get all jar entries
        Enumeration allEntries = jarFile.entries();
        String pluginClassName = null;

        while (allEntries.hasMoreElements()) {

            // Get single file
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) allEntries.nextElement();
            String file = entry.getName();

            // Look for classfiles
            if (file.endsWith(".class")) {

                // Set class name
                String classname = file.replace('/', '.').substring(0, file.length() - 6);

                // Look for plugin class
                if (classname.endsWith("Plugin")) {

                    // Set the class name and exit loop
                    pluginClassName = classname;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Load the class
        ClassLoader pluginLoader = new PluginClassLoader(new URL("file:///" + pluginJarFile));
        Class<?> pluginClass = pluginLoader.loadClass(pluginClassName);

        // Edit as suggested by KDM, still null
        URL settingsUrl = pluginClass.getResource("/settings.xml");
        manifest = parser.load(settingsUrl);

        // Check if manifest has been created
        if (null == manifest) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Manifest file not found in " + pluginJarFile);
        }

        // Create the plugin
        plugin = (Plugin) pluginClass.newInstance();
        plugin.load(manifest);

        return plugin;
    }
}
```

And the autogenerated MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_25-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
```

The `Class-Path` directive is missing, but if i force it to `.` or `./settings.xml` or `settings.xml` (by manually editing the `MANIFEST.MF` file) it won't work either.

This is all I can think of, Thanks in advance for any help

[**EDIT**] I've created an `images/monitor-16.png` into the plugin jar root, added the `#load2` method into the `PluginContainer`.

Since the method is called within a loop I left the `Policy.setPolicy(new PluginSecurityPolicy());` and `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());` inside the constructor.

Here's the new plugn jar structure:

```
TestPlugin.jar
    |
    |---META-INF/
    |   |---MANIFEST.MF
    |
    |---dev.jimbo
    |   |---TestPlugin.class
    |
    |---images
    |   |---monitor-16.png
    |
    |---settings.xml
```

The new method code:

```
private Plugin load2(String pluginJarFile) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {        
    PluginClassLoader urlCL = new PluginClassLoader(new File(pluginJarFile).toURL());
    Class<?> loadClass = urlCL.loadClass("dev.jimbo.TestPlugin");

    System.out.println(loadClass);
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class loader object. Resource = " + urlCL.getResource("images/monitor-16.png"));
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class loader object with absolute path. Resource = " + urlCL.getResource("/images/monitor-16.png"));
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class object. Resource = " + loadClass.getResource("images/monitor-16.png"));
    System.out.println();

    return null;
}
```

Here's the output

```
class dev.jimbo.TestPlugin
Loading the class using the class loader object. Resource = null
Loading the class using the class loader object with absolute path. Resource = null
Loading the class using the class object. Resource = null
```

Comment: After doing some experimentation, I deleted my answer. Using a `URLClassLoader` with a JAR having an image at 'images/load.gif' the `getResource` failed when using '/images/load.gif' but works when 'images/load.gif'. Can you check that out?

Comment: Ok, i tried with a relative path like `URL settingsUrl = pluginClass.getResource("settings.xml")` and `URL settingsUrl = pluginClass.getResource("./settings.xml")`, but it's still null. I tried to put a images folder with an image into the plugin jar, but i still get null. So hoping it could have been netbeans not liking my xml name i renamed the file using my own last name, but it still null :(

Comment: Change the pluginClass to pluginLoader and check.

Comment: Done, null. I tried both relative and absolute path again. I'm starting to think about moving the XML file outside the plugin jar. I don't like it but at list it should work...

Answer (score 0):

The following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Policy.setPolicy(new PluginSecurityPolicy());
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    PluginClassLoader urlCL = new PluginClassLoader(new File(
            "A Jar containing images/load.gif and SampleApp class").toURL());
    Class<?> loadClass = urlCL.loadClass("net.sourceforge.marathon.examples.SampleApp");
    System.out.println(loadClass);
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class loader object. Resource = " + urlCL.getResource("images/load.gif"));
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class loader object with absolute path. Resource = " + urlCL.getResource("/images/load.gif"));
    System.out.println("Loading the class using the class object. Resource = " + loadClass.getResource("images/load.gif"));
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
class net.sourceforge.marathon.examples.SampleApp
Loading the class using the class loader object. Resource = jar:file:/Users/dakshinamurthykarra/Projects/install/marathon/sampleapp.jar!/images/load.gif
Loading the class using the class loader object with absolute path. Resource = null
Loading the class using the class object. Resource = null
```

So I do not think any problem with your class loader. Putting this as an answer so that the code can be formatted properly.

Comment: First thank for the fast reply, I just tried what you suggested, but it gives me back a big fat null, I'll add the attempt to the question code

Comment: Can you try using just 'settings.xml' instead?

Comment: I did it by moving the XML inside the class package and using `pluginLoader.getResource("dev/jimbo/settings.xml")`, but i still get null if i put the XML into the jar root and try witth `pluginLoader.getResource("settings.xml")`, strange.... I'll post a answer if I'll find a solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it! Seems that my previous Netbeans (8.0) was deleting the `plugin` directory from the added Jar/Folder Libraries references on **Clean and Build** action. I've downloaded and installed Netbeans 8.0.2 and the problem was solved. Couldn't find any related bug for that version on their tracker though..

Anyways Thanks for the help :)